# SQL: How to find out if duplicates exists at separate table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates

I'm a little bit lost. I have 2 tables:

```
Table1:    
id1       id2
----------------
uuid-1    uuid-A
uuid-2    uuid-A
uuid-3    uuid-A
uuid-4    uuid-B
uuid-5    uuid-B
uuid-6    uuid-C

Table2:    
id1       data
---------------
uuid-1    aaa
uuid-2    bbb
uuid-3    ccc
uuid-4    ddd
uuid-4    eee
uuid-4    fff
uuid-6    ggg
```

Types of id1 and id2 are *UUID*. Data column is irrelevant.

At `Table1` I should have one to one relation but it's not true. When I have one to many relation - it's a duplicate. Seems, that all of those duplicates at `Table1` and there is low amount of them at `Table2`.

What I need to do is to find if any duplicates exists at `Table2` for some id2.

```
uuid-A -> uuid-1, uuid-2, uuid-3
```

and I can find those 3 uuids at `Table2`. But for

```
uuid-B -> uuid-4, uuid5
```

there are no duplicates at `Table2`, because there is no `uuid-4`.

I have some ideas how to solve. Create SQL function or use python script. Maybe there is other option? Also I'm not sure about best output.

UPD.
Output should be:

```
id1
uuid-1
uuid-2
uuid-3
```

Comment: what did you try so far, and what is the expected output?

Comment: I can only get a list of duplicates id1 from Table1. About output, I need somehow to know if there are duplicates at Table2, if yes, show them.

Comment: Did you try `EXISTS` statement?

Comment: please add the desired output as a table in your question, so we better understand what you want (in a glance).

Comment: @cybork added output

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32606249/905902 duplicate duplicates?

Comment: @wildplasser no, that was related to updates but I don't need them. only to find out if exists.

Comment: So, the desired result are the records that meet this citeria: if a value in Table1.id2 is there more than 1 time, AND all the corresponding Table1.id1's are found in Table2.id1. Right?

Comment: @cybork I would say if there is relation one(id2) to many(id1) at Table1 and there are more than one id1 at Table 2, show those id1.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't seem to understand it. Would a join with 
where count(distinct Table1.id2)>1 AND count(distinct Table2.id1)>1 solve it? I leave now, hopefully I see the answer to your question later. Succes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select table1.id1 from table2
inner join table1 using(id1)
where id2 in  ( select id2 from table1
    inner join table2 using(id1)
    group by id2 having count(distinct id1)>1)
```

This will show you all the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

```
with subq (id1, id2) as (
     select id1, id2
     from table1 
     where 
     exists (select 1 from table2 where table2.id1=table1.id1)
     )

select id1 from subq
    where exists (
    select  
    t.id2
    ,   count(id1) 
    from subq as t
    where subq.id2 = t.id2
    group by id2
    having count(id1) > 1
    )
```